# Multiple buttons with same class, how to loop through them with EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am trying to make a webpage with a collection of clickable images, when user clicks an image a popup (related to the image) should open.
There are multiple images which should open the same popup.

For example the first and 3rd image on the page should both open the popup with `id="popupApeldoorn"`.

Which popup should be opened when clicking on an image is determined based on the class of the image link. Therefore multiple images will have the same class in my example.

I'm using `getElementsByClassName` which returns an array/list (I store the output of the `getElementsByClassName` in a variable and apply the eventlistener to this variable).

Currently I am applying the eventlisteners to the first (index 0) item in the list returned by `getElementsByClassName` and therefore if there are multiple images with the same class name, the eventlistener will only be applied to the first item (clickable image) on the webpage.

I want all images which have the class `image-linkApeldoorn` to open the popup "popupApeldoorn" but I don't know how to loop through the list which is returned by the `getelementsbyclassname` method..

Does anyone know a good approach to this?

Or should I perhaps be using QueryselectorAll or something similar instead of my current selector?

Thank you!

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
    <style>
        /* CSS styles */
    /* The modal (background) */
    .modal {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); /* Black w/ opacity */
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;

    }

    /* Modal Content/Box */
    .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 10% auto; /* 10% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div  class="imageTextGrid" name="overview">
            <!-- <img id="btnHanne" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" /> -->
            
            <!-- <a href="#" id="image-link">
                <img src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="Image">
              </a> -->
              
            <a href="#" class="image-linkApeldoorn"><img class="btnApeldoorn" src="img1" /></a>
            <a href="#" class="image-linkIjsselmuiden1"><img class="btnIjsselmuiden1" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>                        
            <a href="#" class="image-linkApeldoorn"><img class="btnApeldoorn" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" class="image-linkHanne"><img class="btnHanne" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" class="image-linkApeldoorn"><img class="btnApeldoorn" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" class="image-linkRobin"><img class="btnApeldoorn" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" class="image-linkHanne"><img class="btnIjsselmuiden1" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" class="image-linkIjsselmuiden2"><img class="btnIjsselmuiden1" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>
            
            <!-- <p>mooi huisje met warmtepomp en schaaldelen enzo en nieuwe ramen en epdm dak en goed geisoleerd wouw wat een moi verhaaltje. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas eaque, eos corporis facere illo ipsum repellendus! Nesciunt, optio mollitia veniam earum praesentium, labore ut doloremque porro soluta necessitatibus aliquid amet!</p> -->
        </div>

        <!-- popups -->

    <button id="myBtn">Open Popup</button>
        <!-- standard -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                standard popup
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Ijsselmuiden 1 -->
        <div id="popupIjsselmuiden1" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ijsselmuiden1 popup
            </div>
        </div>    
        
        <!-- Ijsselmuiden 2 -->
        <div id="popupIjsselmuiden2" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ijsselmuiden2 popup
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Apeldoorn -->
        <div id="popupApeldoorn" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                apeldoorn Popup
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Hanne -->
        <div id="popupHanne" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                hanne Popup
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Robin -->
        <div id="popupRobin" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                robin Popup
            </div>
        </div>

        </body>

    <script>

        // Get buttons (image text grids)
        const imageLinkApeldoorn = document.getElementsByClassName("image-linkApeldoorn")[0];
        const imageLinkIjsselmuiden1 = document.getElementsByClassName("image-linkIjsselmuiden1")[0];
        const imageLinkIjsselmuiden2 = document.getElementsByClassName("image-linkIjsselmuiden2")[0];
        const imageLinkHanne = document.getElementsByClassName("image-linkHanne")[0];
        const imageLinkRobin = document.getElementsByClassName("image-linkRobin")[0];

        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
        var btnIjsselmuiden1 = document.getElementsByClassName("btnIjsselmuiden1")[0];
        var btnIjsselmuiden2 = document.getElementsByClassName("btnIjssemluiden2")[0];
        var btnApeldoorn = document.getElementsByClassName("btnApeldoorn")[0];
        var btnHanne = document.getElementsByClassName("btnHanne")[0];
        var btnRobin = document.getElementsByClassName("btnRobin")[0];

        // Get the popup sections
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
        var popupIjsselmuiden1 = document.getElementById("popupIjsselmuiden1");
        var popupIjsselmuiden2 = document.getElementById("popupIjsselmuiden2");
        var popupApeldoorn = document.getElementById("popupApeldoorn");
        var popupHanne = document.getElementById("popupHanne");
        var popupRobin = document.getElementById("popupRobin");

        // When the user clicks a button (or image), open relevant section
        
        //Apeldoorn
        imageLinkApeldoorn.addEventListener("click", function(event) { // open popup when user clicks on image 
        event.preventDefault();
        popupApeldoorn.style.opacity = 1;
        popupApeldoorn.style.opacity = 1;
        popupApeldoorn.style.display = "block";
        });

        popupApeldoorn.addEventListener("click", function(event) { //close popup when user clicks outside of popup
        if (event.target === popupApeldoorn) {
            popupApeldoorn.style.opacity = 0;
            popupApeldoorn.style.display = "none";
        }
        });
        
        //Ijsselmuiden 1
        imageLinkIjsselmuiden1.addEventListener("click", function(event) { // open popup when user clicks on image 
        event.preventDefault();
        popupIjsselmuiden1.style.opacity = 1;
        popupIjsselmuiden1.style.opacity = 1;
        popupIjsselmuiden1.style.display = "block";
        });

        popupIjsselmuiden1.addEventListener("click", function(event) { //close popup when user clicks outside of popup
        if (event.target === popupIjsselmuiden1) {
            popupIjsselmuiden1.style.opacity = 0;
            popupIjsselmuiden1.style.display = "none";
        }
        });
        
        //Ijsselmuiden 2
        imageLinkIjsselmuiden2.addEventListener("click", function(event) { // open popup when user clicks on image 
        event.preventDefault();
        popupIjsselmuiden2.style.opacity = 1;
        popupIjsselmuiden2.style.opacity = 1;
        popupIjsselmuiden2.style.display = "block";
        });

        popupIjsselmuiden2.addEventListener("click", function(event) { //close popup when user clicks outside of popup
        if (event.target === popupIjsselmuiden2) {
            popupIjsselmuiden2.style.opacity = 0;
            popupIjsselmuiden2.style.display = "none";
        }
        });

        //Hanne
        imageLinkHanne.addEventListener("click", function(event) { // open popup when user clicks on image 
        event.preventDefault();
        popupHanne.style.opacity = 1;
        popupHanne.style.opacity = 1;
        popupHanne.style.display = "block";
        });

        popupHanne.addEventListener("click", function(event) { //close popup when user clicks outside of popup
        if (event.target === popupHanne) {
            popupHanne.style.opacity = 0;
            popupHanne.style.display = "none";
        }
        });

        //Robin
        imageLinkRobin.addEventListener("click", function(event) { // open popup when user clicks on image 
        event.preventDefault();
        popupRobin.style.opacity = 1;
        popupRobin.style.opacity = 1;
        popupRobin.style.display = "block";
        });

        popupRobin.addEventListener("click", function(event) { //close popup when user clicks outside of popup
        if (event.target === popupRobin) {
            popupRobin.style.opacity = 0;
            popupRobin.style.display = "none";
        }
        });


        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modal.style.opacity = "0";
            setTimeout(function(){
                modal.style.opacity = "1";
                }, 100);
        }

    
        //end of button actions

        
        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the popup, close it

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: There are two ways. Either you look through the node list using forEach and apply an event listener to each - see this article in [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/) for an example. The better one imho is to use [event delegation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/event-delegation-in-javascript/) where you put the listener on the parent but pick up the actual element clicked using event.target.

Comment: Thank you @Adam! I have modified the code using delegation and got it partially working :) however I am still unable to get the popup to close when user clicks outside the popup after it's opened using delegation, i get the error ("TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')") saying that "element" (my variable storing the popup) is undefined in the last section of the JS code. Please see the edit to my original post (I've added the code modified with delegation to the post on the bottom).

Could you please take a look what i am doing wrong? Thank you again!

Comment: @Adam I managed to fix it, my "element" variable was indeed undefined at the time the second part of the JS code was running since none of the images had been clicked yet the element var was still undefined. I fixed it by nesting the code (which adds the event listener to the popup) inside the code for adding the eventlistener to the imageTextGrid such that the 2nd eventlistener only gets added when user has already clicked one of the images anbd therefore "element" will be defined at that point in time :)

Comment: @Adam if you want to add it as an answer i'll be sure to accept it.

Comment: If you fixed it then you should answer your own question and get the upvote yourself :-) Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code using delegation and got it partially working :) however I am still unable to get the popup to close when user clicks outside the popup after it's opened using delegation, i get the error ("TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')") saying that "element" (my variable storing the popup) is undefined in the last section of the JS code.

I managed to fix it, my "element" variable was indeed undefined at the time the second part of the JS code was running since none of the images had been clicked yet the element var was still undefined. I fixed it by nesting the code (which adds the event listener to the popup) inside the code for adding the eventlistener to the imageTextGrid such that the 2nd eventlistener only gets added when user has already clicked one of the images anbd therefore "element" will be defined at that point in time :)

Code below

```js
const imageTextGrid = document.getElementById("imageTextGrid");
var element; //initial declaration of element var, which stores popup item

//open relevant popup when image is clicked
imageTextGrid.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.className); //logs classname of image; use classname of image as argument for function which shows popup related to image
  event.preventDefault();
  element = document.querySelector("#" + event.target.className);
  element.style.opacity = 1;
  element.style.display = "block";
  //close popup when user clicks outside of image
  element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target === element) {
      element.style.opacity = 0;
      element.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* CSS styles */


/* The modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}


/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 10% auto;
  /* 10% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="imageTextGrid" name="overview">
    <a href="#" class="image-link"><img class="popupHanne" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>
    <a href="#2" class="image-link2"><img class="popupIjsselmuiden" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>
    <a href="#2" class="image-link2"><img class="popupApeldoorn" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>
    <a href="#2" class="image-link2"><img class="popupApeldoorn" src="https://www.webfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/generic-image-placeholder.png" /></a>

  </div>

  <!-- popup -->

  <div id="popupIjsselmuiden" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Popup Ijsselmuiden
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="popupApeldoorn" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Popup Apeldoorn
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="popupHanne" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      PopupHanne
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```